# How to query multiple table and using additional

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have some tables to make a table from query ordered by final score.
I can do it using couples of query and php to make it happen but I don't know how to order by final_score DESC.
Im using mysql 5.6 and PHP
Please Help.

### Existing tables

table peserta

> | id_peserta | name |
>
> ---
>
> | 1 | mr. one | 
>   | 2 | mr. two |

table nilai

> | id_nilai | id_peserta | nilai_a | nilai_b | nilai_c|
>
> ---
>
> | 1 | 1 | 70 | 80 | 90 | 
>   | 2 | 2 | 85 | 95 | 75 |

table center

> | id_center | center_name |
>
> ---
>
> | 1 | center1 |
>   | 2 | center2 |
>   | 3 | center3 |

table essay

> | id_essay | id_center | id_peserta | nilai_e |
>
> ---
>
> | 1 | 1 | 1 | 65 | 
>   | 2 | 2 | 1 | 60 | 
>   | 3 | 3 | 1 | 50 | 
>   | 4 | 1 | 2 | 55 |

### I need something like this one:

> | id_peserta | name | center1 | center2 | center3 | total_center | nilai_a | nilai_b | nilai_c | total_nilai | final_score | passed/failed |
>
> ---
>
> | 1 | mr. one | 65 | 60 | 50 | 175=65+60+50 | 70 | 80 | 90 | 250=70+80+90 | 425=175+250 | passed | 
>   | 2 | mr. two | 55 |   |   | 55 | 85 | 75 | 95 | 265=85+75+95 | 320=55+265 | failed |

order by final_score

Comment: Please explain which software you are using and asking about.

Comment: im using Mysql 5.6 and PHP

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point:

```
select n.id_peserta, n_sum+coalesce(e_sum,0) as final_score, center_count from
    (select id_peserta, sum(nilai_a+nilai_b+nilai_c) as n_sum from nilai
    group by id_peserta, nilai_a+nilai_b+nilai_c) n
left join
    (select id_peserta, sum(nilai_e) as e_sum, count(1) as center_count from essay
    group by id_peserta) e
on n.id_peserta = e.id_peserta
order by n_sum+coalesce(e_sum,0) DESC
```

The number of "nilai" seems static (as already part of a table structure). But the number of centers is designed to be dynamic. Therefore I would not "crosstab" it but show a count of visited centers instead.

It may be worth to challenge the data model design, but above should give you the desired answer based on the given structure.

Working assumption: nilai.id_peserta is a unique key.

Regards
Ralph

(written in text editor without testing, so you may run into a typo)

Answer (score 0):

Separate the results of the two parts.

first part

```
SELECT p.id_peserta, p.name, n.nilai_a, n.nilai_b, n.nilai_c, 
(n.nilai_a+n.nilai_b+n.nilai_c) as total_nilai 
FROM peserta p LEFT JOIN nilai n ON p.id_peserta=n.id_nilai
```

the second part

```
SELECT e.id_peserta, SUM(IF(c.center_name='center1', nilai_e, 0)) as center1 ,
SUM(IF(c.center_name='center2', nilai_e, 0)) as center2 ,
SUM(IF(c.center_name='center3', nilai_e, 0)) as center3 ,SUM(e.nilai_e) AS total_center
FROM essay e LEFT JOIN center c ON e.id_center=c.id_center GROUP BY e.id_peserta
```

and then merge

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.center1, t2.center2, t2.center3, t2.total_center, 
(t1.total_nilai+t2.total_center) as final_score, IF((t1.total_nilai+t2.total_center)>400, 'passed', 'failed') as `passed/failed` 
FROM(
((SELECT p.id_peserta, p.name, n.nilai_a, n.nilai_b, n.nilai_c, 
(n.nilai_a+n.nilai_b+n.nilai_c) as total_nilai 
FROM peserta p LEFT JOIN nilai n ON p.id_peserta=n.id_nilai)) t1, 
(SELECT e.id_peserta, SUM(IF(c.center_name='center1', nilai_e, 0)) as center1 ,
SUM(IF(c.center_name='center2', nilai_e, 0)) as center2 ,
SUM(IF(c.center_name='center3', nilai_e, 0)) as center3 ,SUM(e.nilai_e) AS total_center
FROM essay e LEFT JOIN center c ON e.id_center=c.id_center GROUP BY e.id_peserta) t2)
WHERE t1.id_peserta=t2.id_peserta 
ORDER BY final_score DESC;
```